# How could we pass a different value on an Item select from android spinner than the text which we select in spinner?

Tags: android

I created a spinner displaying names of all the countries in the world. Now, I would like to pass a value like AFG for Afghanistan, ITA for Italy,etc to be stored as string upon selection of the Item from spinner. I am confused about how to do this. Since, I am assigning the full name of countries in spinner and want to pass a different data than the country name(like I said ITA for Italy when its selected) when Spinner is clicked.

Comment: Map country name to country ISO names, select italy, lookup in map, get ITA.

Comment: if you are storing country name in database , create another entry for  it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can do for two things, one if you want to use in code but not want to see in selection other name, and second one is if you want to display name in spinner and also use in code check below solution.

**Create one common class to store country names and country codes like below**

CommonClass.java

```
  //I am taking it as CommonClass you can change it.

  public static final String[] strCountryNames = {"India","Italy","Afghanistan","United States of America"};

  public static final String[] strCountryCodes = {"IND","ITA","AFG","USA"};
```

Now, For spinner setAdapter use CommonClass.strCountryNames,

And where you want to use code there use CommonClass.strCountryCode,

Suppose you want to get code for India, then you can check it as

```
 CommonClass.strCountryCode[spinner.selectyedPosition];
```

Comment: This is working in my code.

Answer (score 2):

Create your Object pojo like

```
class Country{
 String name;
String  code;

//getter and setters
    }
```

and set list of Country 
`List<Country> list;` to adapter

Show country **name** and access country **code**

```
spinner.getSelectedItem().getCode();
```

Comment: This is working too.

Comment: declaring two separate  array will do the task , but this is what the OOP is

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing the full country name, you can get the selected country and call on `str.substring(0, 3).toUpperCase()`

Comment: What in case of United States of America , 
It should be USA

Answer (score 0):

if you want first three latter of name

```
String countryName = "China"
String shortName = countryName.substring(3).toUpperCase();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
       public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
         int pos = spinner.getSelectedItemPosition();
String mysourcestring= yourarraylistname[+pos];
String substr=mysourcestring.substring(0,3).toUpperCase();
}
 @Override
       public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

      }
});
```

now the value you want to pass will be in substr.
sorry if any errors,
hope this helps